# For loop in Scrapy returns full response multiple times

Tags: python, for-loop, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a webpage containing a tv-guide (movies with their channel and starting time). The structure of the webpage looks like this:

```
<div class="grid__col__inner">
    <div class="tv-guide__channel">
        <h6>
            <a href="./tv-gids/2be/vandaag">2BE</a>
        </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="program">
        <div class="time">22:20</div>
        <div class="title"><a href="./2be/vandaag/knowing">Knowing</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The webpage has multiple grid__col__inner divs. One for each channel. Each channel can contain multiple movies.

I wrote a spider with the Scrapy framework as follows:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for col_inner in response.xpath('//div[@class="grid__col__inner"]'):
            chnl = col_inner.xpath('//div[@class="tv-guide__channel"]/h6/a/text()').extract()
            for program in col_inner.xpath('//div[@class="program"]'):
                item = TVGuideItem()
                item['channel'] = chnl
                item['start_ts'] = program.xpath('//div[@class="time"]/text()').extract()
                item['title'] = program.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
                yield item
```

Because the channel name is only mentioned once in the grid__col__inner div, I extract it first and assign it to each item (movie).

When I run this code, it returns the full result (all channels with all movies) for each grid__col__inner. Below you see the result of one run of the for-loop. When I run it, it returns this same result multiple times.

> {'channel': [u'VTM',
>                u'VITAYA',
>                u'PRIME STAR',
>                u'PRIME ACTION',
>                u'PRIME FAMILY',
>                u'PRIME FEZZTIVAL',
>                u'NPO3'],
>    'start_ts': [u'22:30',
>                 u'13:35',
>                 u'20:35',
>                 u'06:30',
>                 u'08:00',
>                 u'09:40',
>                 u'11:00'],
>    'title': [u'Another 48 Hrs',
>              u'Double Bill',
>              u'Man zkt Vrouw',
>              u'82 dagen in april',
>              u'Rio 2',
>              u'Epizoda u zivotu beraca zeljeza',
>              u'300: Rise of an Empire']}

Am I doing something wrong with the for-loop here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this documentation from scrapy:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths

When you are doing:

```
chnl = col_inner.xpath('//div[@class="tv-guide__channel"]/h6/a/text()').extract()
```

You are extracting all the //div[@class="tv-guide__channel"] elements in the document, because // is searching across all the document. Instead try this:

```
chnl = col_inner.xpath('.//div[@class="tv-guide__channel"]/h6/a/text()').extract()
```

the .// will execute the search relative to the current node.
You have to do the same with the rest of the selectors:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    for col_inner in response.xpath('//div[@class="grid__col__inner"]'):
        chnl = col_inner.xpath('.//div[@class="tv-guide__channel"]/h6/a/text()').extract()
        for program in col_inner.xpath('.//div[@class="program"]'):
            item = TVGuideItem()
            item['channel'] = chnl
            item['start_ts'] = program.xpath('.//div[@class="time"]/text()').extract()
            item['title'] = program.xpath('.//div[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Read this documentation from scrapy:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths